# How to parse a child XML property with C# using XmlDocument?

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

Here's an example of the `xml` file I'm working with:

```
<PhysicalChains>
    <Chain IDValue="Chilis">
        <ChainID>
            <BrandName>Chilis Restaurant</BrandName>
            <Information>
                <PhoneNumber>111-222-3333</PhoneNumber>
            </Information>
        </ChainID>
    </Chain>
    <Chain IDValue="Longhorn">
        <ChainID>
            <BrandName>Longhorn Bar and Grill</BrandName>
            <Information>
                <PhoneNumber>555-222-4444</PhoneNumber>
            </Information>
        </ChainID>
    </Chain>
    ...
    ...
</PhysicalChains>
```

I'm simply trying to pull the children properties to output this format:

```
Restaurant ID: Chilis
Restaurant Name: Chilis Restaurant
Restaurant Phone Number: 111-222-3333

Restaurant ID: Longhorn
Restaurant Name: Longhorn Bar and Grill
Restaurant Phone Number: 555-222-4444

....
....
```

Here's the code I have so far:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml("https://example.com/feeds/myFeed.xml");

XmlNodeList nodes = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/PhysicalChains/Chain");

foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    // This first line works just fine.
    Console.WriteLine("Resturant ID: " + node.Attributes["IDValue"].Value + "\n");

    // I need to know how to pull the other information above here

}
```

I've tried getting `BrandName` property like so, but it didn't work:

```
Console.WriteLine("Restaurant Name: " + node.SelectSingleNode("BrandName").InnerText + "\n");
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: If it's an option Linq has enough support to let you do this in one statement.  Searching Liqn Xml here has tons of relevant q's with a's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just use `SelectSingleNode` to directly reach a child of a child node.  First, navigate to the `ChainID` node, then try to navigate to the `BrandName` node.  Like so:

```
var child1 = node.SelectSingleNode("ChainID");
var child2 = child1.SelectSingleNode("BrandName");

Console.WriteLine("Restaurant Name: " + child2.InnerText + "\n\n");
```